# Dynamic inline validation with individual grails domain class attributes

Tags: grails, grails-validation

Currently all form validation in our applicaation is performed when the form is submitted.
Each CommandObject has multiple fields and therefore multiple constraints and checks.

We are looking to adjust the validation so that errors appear inline when the user tabs away from each field (onblur).

I'm relatively new to grails so would appreciate any suggestions on possible plugins or best practice ways to approach this?

Examples or links to good tutorials would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but seems that the [JQuery Validation UI plugin](http://limcheekin.github.com/jquery-validation-ui/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'll give that a go and see how it performs. Thanks Sérgio.